# Spring Boot Thin Jar with Gradle not working

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, spring-boot-gradle-plugin

I tried to switch to a Spring Boot thin jar so that the dependencies are not included in the jar. I am using the `thin-launcher` gradle plugin:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot.experimental.thin-launcher' version '1.0.25.RELEASE'
}
```

However, I am getting the following error message when running the `thinJar` task:

> The value of a manifest attribute must not be null (Key=Start-Class).

I tried to specify the `Start-Class` attribute in several ways:

```
thinJar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Start-Class': "at.mypackage.Application"
    }
}

bootJar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Start-Class': "at.mypackage.Application"
    }
}
```

Using the gradle `application` plugin and specifying the `mainClassName` property does not work either. Without the thin jar plugin, everything works as expected.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

**Update 2021-02-27**: The issue got resolved with [PR #164](https://github.com/spring-projects-experimental/spring-boot-thin-launcher/pull/164). It's now compatible with Gradle 6.8.x.

**Original answer**: It looks like you're affected by [issue #149](https://github.com/spring-projects-experimental/spring-boot-thin-launcher/issues/149) - "Getting an error about missing the value of a manifest attribute (Start-Class)". There's no solution at the time of writing this answer. The project maintainers are asking for help.

Workarounds mentioned:

1. Use Gradle 5
2. Use Gradle 6.0.1 - that's what the [simple example](https://github.com/spring-projects-experimental/spring-boot-thin-launcher/blob/14560b79eaa35d15400951193dfbe24576b05874/samples/simple) is using